# Trouble with HTML/CSS transitions

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I'm working on adding transitions like the ones on this website:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/08/circle-hover-effects-with-css-transitions/

More specifically, I'm trying to do example #6. I've followed the code exactly, but it still isn't working. Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/S2Wzj/

I looked through, and I think the CSS code is causing the problem. At a few points, its background is set to something like

```
background: #f9f9f9 url(../images/bg.jpg);
```

This code is taken direction from the tympanus website and I think it may not work because I do not have the image linked. Here's the effect I would like: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/index6.html

Comment: So your question is Why is this image that I do not have uploaded not showing up?

Comment: I mean is there a way to find the image?... Or do I need to find my own that will match the style.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is just not showing up then it's probably because the image isn't actually in the right path, for it to show properly you should grab bg.jpg and put it in an images folder **one directory up** from the html/css folders. So, your structure would look a bit like this,

```
root
    source
        index.html
        stylesheet.css
    images
        bg.jpg
```

Does that answer your question?

EDIT: misunderstood the question, image can be found here http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/images/bg.jpg

Comment: Where could I find the image? That's my problem, it's in the local part of the website but I can't find where it's stored.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/images/bg.jpg

Sorry, i misunderstood your question

Comment: Oh wow thanks so much! Upvote for you ;) **edit**: Nevermind sorry I need 15 rep to upvote you :(

Comment: It still isn't working :/ It's supposed to drop down and look like http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircleHoverEffects/index6.html and now it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/S2Wzj/1/

Comment: Here is fiddle with proper path to the images [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRANIS/S2Wzj/2/)  ...